# Extracting Table Info from website using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm very much a BeautifulSoup noob and am trying to extract match scores from the website flashscores.co.uk with little luck!

This is my code so far:

---

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

flash = "http://www.flashscore.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/"

prem = urllib2.urlopen(flash)

soup = BeautifulSoup(prem, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'soccer'})

for row in table.FindAll("span")

print (row.text)
```

---

Here is an image of the Page Source I'm trying to extract the info from. A good starting point would be to display:
Chelsea 4
Manchester United 0

[Page Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfb93.png)

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML containing the table information is actually generated by JavaScript. `urllib2` does not process JavaScript.

What you linked to as the "page source" is actually the DOM **after your browser has processed the JavaScript**.  If you load the page with javascript disabled, you'll find that the results never load.

Instead, you will need to use something like `selenium`, which will process JavaScript.